# Programatically get AWS RDS connection string

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there a way through the aws api to get the connection string for a RDS database? Something in the form of:

`postgres://username:password@host/db_name`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there's no API call that will build that string for you.

However, using the [DescribeDBInstances API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeDBInstances.html) you can retrieve the `MasterUsername`, `DBName` ("the name of the initial database of this instance that was provided at create time, if one was specified when the DB instance was created") and host (through the `Endpoint.Address` field) and build the string yourself.

For the password, you'll have to provide it yourself in a secure manner, since RDS cannot retrieve it through API calls.

Comment: Does RDS still not provide any way to retrieve password. Else how should password be supplied in case of RDS?

Comment: Retrieving the password in plaintext would probably be a security issue. However, you can generate temporary passwords using [`GetClusterCredentials`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_GetClusterCredentials.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, going through the documentation of GetClusterCredentials, it generates temporary passwords for AWS Redshift, does this api also generate temporary password for databases from AWS RDS?

Comment: No, GetClusterCredentials is for Redshift only.